# emailing from log4j

Tags: java, logging, smtp, log4j, appender

I currently email errors logged through log4j with:

```
<appender name="email" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="localhost"/>
    <param name="From" value="notifications@mydomain.com"/>
    <param name="To" value="me@mydomain.com"/>
    <param name="Subject" value="Error from mydomain.com"/>
</appender>
```

works great, but I'd really like to email me occasionally from a particular log file.  This other log file, I also want even the INFO events that are logged.  How do I do that?  If I try to setup another emailAppender, or just use this emailAppender, nothing gets emailed because there seems to be a filter on ERROR or worse events.  So I tried adding a LevelRangeFilter:

```
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO"/>
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL"/>
    </filter>
```

But it has no effect on an SMTPAppender :(.

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html) it looks like this appender uses a super special TriggeringEventEvaluator as a filtering mechanism. You can probably fix this by creating your appender with an evaluator that always returns true. I'm not sure though.